# "Partition" of a smooth function in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

This is a question asking for reference.

I have a proof of the following.

Let $f=f(x,y)$ be a smooth function  in $\mathbb R^2$ which vanishes at the origin. Then there exist smooth functions $f_1=f_1(xy,x)$ and $f_2=f_2(xy,y)$ such that $f=f_1+f_2$.

Its proof consists on: 1) deal with the formal problem, 2) deal with the flat terms.

However I do not think such a result is new, it must exist somewhere in the literature. Maybe in some more general context. Does anybody knows a reference for such a result?

**Edit:** Let me give a bit more detail. The formal series of $f$ can be written as

\begin{equation}
\hat f=\sum_{i,j\geq 0}a_{ij}x^iy^j
\end{equation}

and can be partitioned as

\begin{equation}
\hat f=\hat f_1+\hat f_2=\sum_{i\geq j}a_{ij}(xy)^jx^{i-j}+\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}(xy)^iy^{j-i}.
\end{equation}

Then, by Borel's lemma there exist smooth functions $f_1(xy,x)$ and $f_2(xy,y)$ such that
$$
f=f_1+f_2+h(x,y)
$$

where $h$ is flat. The next step is to "kill" the flat term. I won't go into the detail, but this should be enough to get the idea behind the proof.

Comment: Did you not mean $f_2(x,xy)$ instead of $f_2(xy,y)$?

Comment: @GHfromMO nope, I really meant what is written. Imagine in the formal series expansion of the form $x^iy^j$, $f_1$ contains monomials where $i\geq j$ and $f_2$ the rest.

Comment: Well, the notation $f_1=f_1(xy,x)$ etc. is confusing in itself. Also, it is not clear to me what you mean by formal series expansion. In short, it is not clear to me what you are stating.

Comment: The 'formal series expansion' is the Taylor series of $f$.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you mean. By $f_1$ we abbreviate the function $f_1(x,y)$. The function $f_1(xy,y)$ derived from it is a different object, e.g. for $f_1(x,y):=xy$ we have $f_1(xy,y)=xy^2$. It is not clear which of the two is smooth, and which of the two is used in the decomposition. It is also not clear to me what you mean by a flat function.

Comment: I also don't see what is the role of $\hat f$ in the EDIT section. I am not asking about the proof of your result, but about what the result says.

Comment: Both $f_i$ are smooth. Both are used at the decomposition. That is why I showed at least the formal level of the proof. Flat means zero Taylor expansion. 
The result means that a function in two variables may be partitioned as showed. The importance is that it can be done at the level of smooth functions and not only at the level of formal functions. My application is in dynamical systems for example. It may happen that $xy$ is a first integral (a constant along the trajectories of a vector field). Then it is much easier to integrate, say $f$, if we have such a result.

Comment: By $f_1$ we abbreviate the smooth function of the variables $(xy,x)$ and by $f_2$ the smooth function of the variables $(xy,y)$. Just as shown in the expansion above. Call $w=xy$, then $\hat f_1(w,x)=\sum a_{mn}w^mx^n$ and $\hat f_2(w,y)=\sum a_{mn}w^my^n$, and make the coefficients coincide. Some of them are zero if necessary.

Comment: @GHfromMO Formally, you are right. The statement means: For all $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ with $f(0,0)=0$ there are $g_1,g_2 \in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ such that $f(x,y)=g_1(xy,x)+g_2(xy,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Well there is not much difference from what I wrote.  What @JochenWengenroth wrote above is correct. I hope things are clear now.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth: Thanks for the clarification. I understand the statement now, as well as PepeToro's comments.